Is Salesforce's refresh token rotation working?
I have enabled the refresh token rotation for my connected app.
My expectation is that when I use my refresh token to acquire a new access token, the current refresh token should expire and a new refresh token should be returned.
But that's not the case.
How does the rotation work ?

Sometimes it takes near 15 minutes for connected app to be updated (based on personal experience). So it might take time when this works

That doesn't seem to be the case.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.

Also, in the oauth refresh token flow, the refresh token was not even part of response. I assume it should be there optionally at least. Otherwise, cannot think of a way how it could work.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5
